# Hide or Custom page for ionic 2 Error handling box

Tags: cordova, ionic2

In application using ionic 2 when an error happens a dialog like below appears:

[image]

**I don't want user to see this screen** when any error happens. Instead of this I want to route the user to some custom page or my root page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is only shown in `ionic serve` and is a feature of [IonicErrorHandler](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/IonicErrorHandler/).

> The IonicErrorHandler intercepts the default Console error handling and displays runtime errors as an overlay when using Ionic's Dev Build Server.

This is set in `ngModule`.

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
```

It does not display that page in device or emulator.

You can extend `ErrorHandler` class and set it to do what you need.

```
export declare class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor(){}

    handleError(err: any){
    }
}
```

And in `ngModule`:

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler },
```